# Get value of attribute when iterating over array of objects (getting nils)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my `Guest` model, I have this method to return a list of ids from an associated model:

```
def self.people_list(consultant_id)
  # returns an array of ids of people who attended parties for a given consultant
  people = self.select(:person_id).joins('INNER JOIN parties ON guests.party_id = parties.id').where('parties.consultant_id = ?', consultant_id).collect{ |g| g.person_id }
end
```

`person_id` is a field in the Guest model. But what I'm getting back is an array of nils. From rails console I can tell that the query is correct, and it is returning the correct number of objects. I'm just not getting them into the array.

Thank you for you help.

P.S., In case it helps/matters, Consultants have many Parties, which have many Guests. The Guests has a person_id, which joins to the People table. I'm trying to find all the person_ids from the Guests table that have been to a party for a given consultant.

From the console (after changing to rails associations syntax as noted below)

```
Guest Load (0.3ms)  SELECT person_id FROM `guests` INNER JOIN `parties` ON `parties`.`id` = `guests`.`party_id` WHERE (parties.consultant_id = 1)
=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

Comment: start by removing the "INNER JOIN" and use the rails associations instead, e.g. Guest(:consultant_id).parties  If the behaviour in the console is diff to the app, then you are using different ID's

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should approach this as the consultant being the primary object.

```
def attendees
  @attendees = []
  parties.each do |p|
    @attendees << p.guests.collect(&:person_id)
  end
  @attendees
end
```

Then call that method on the consultant object.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to minimize the number of sql calls, as this method will get called frequently. I agree it belongs in Consultant, though. I think I can refactor to do that.

Answer (score 0):

So, I realized I had attr_accessor on :people_id, which is what caused the nils. I need to leave that in for another party of the system, but I was able to get the correct values by replacing g.person_id with g[:person_id].

I don't quite understand why, but it works...

Comment: Using the `[]` notation to access an attribute bypasses the method on the object to get the attribute value.  So you're basically bypassing the getter that you created via `attr_acessor :people_id` when you use `g[:person_id]`